# docker-compose up error: "failed to solve: rpc error: code = Unknown desc = failed to solve with frontend dockerfile.v0"

Tags: docker, docker-compose

I'm pretty new with using docker and especially docker-compose and i'm trying to create a docker-compose but it fails with:
"failed to solve: rpc error: code = Unknown desc = failed to solve with frontend dockerfile.v0: failed to read dockerfile: open /var/lib/docker/tmp/buildkit-mount155987974/Dockerfile: no such file or directory".
My docker-compose looks like this:

```
version: '3.7'
services:
  document-mongo:
    image: mongo:latest
    environment:
      MONGO_INITDB_ROOT_USERNAME: root
      MONGO_INITDB_ROOT_PASSWORD: rootpassword
    ports:
      - 27017:27017
    volumes:
      - mongodb_data_container:/data/db
  keyring-mongo:
    image: mongo:latest
    environment:
      MONGO_INITDB_ROOT_USERNAME: root
      MONGO_INITDB_ROOT_PASSWORD: rootpassword
    ports:
      - 27018:27017
    volumes:
      - mongodb_data_container2:/data/db
  document-api:
    build:
      context: https://github.com/International-Data-Spaces-Association/ids-clearing-house-core.git
    container_name: "document-api"
    depends_on:
        - keyring-api
        - document-mongo
    environment:
        # Allowed levels: Off, Error, Warn, Info, Debug, Trace
        - API_LOG_LEVEL=Info
    ports:
        - "8001:8001"
    volumes:
        - ./data/document-api/Rocket.toml:/server/Rocket.toml
        - ./data/certs:/server/certs
  keyring-api:
    build:
      context: https://github.com/International-Data-Spaces-Association/ids-clearing-house-core.git
    container_name: "keyring-api"
    depends_on:
        - keyring-mongo
    environment:
        # Allowed levels: Off, Error, Warn, Info, Debug, Trace
        - API_LOG_LEVEL=Info
    ports:
        - "8002:8002"
    volumes:
        - ./data/keyring-api/init_db:/server/init_db
        - ./data/keyring-api/Rocket.toml:/server/Rocket.toml
        - ./data/certs:/server/certs
volumes:
  mongodb_data_container:
  mongodb_data_container2:
```

OS: Windows 10
Does anyone know how to fix this error?

Comment: The GitHub repository you name as the `build: {context:}` doesn't include a `Dockerfile` in its root directory.

Comment: oh thanks! i've changed the context to the lokal path where the docker files are but the error is still the same.

Comment: Try removing the `build:` section altogether. This worked for me in a different scenario.

Comment: How exactly do you invoke `docker compose`?

Answer (score 2):

Try to use

```
DOCKER_BUILDKIT=0 docker-compose build
docker-compose up
```

source : https://docs.docker.com/build/buildkit/

Answer (score 0):

Try to erase cache.

"Disk usage" extension for docker desktop very helpful.